# With C#/.NET HttpClient, is there a way to directly access the underlying HttpWebResponse's response Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm using HttpClient, and I'd prefer not to re-write all my code to stop using it.

I want direct access to the response's content stream so that I can process it as it comes off the wire, and avoid ballooning memory consumption.

Underneath the crusty outer layer of HttpClientHandler lies HttpWebResponse, which provides direct access via GetResponseStream(). In fact, HttpClientHandler is building a StreamContent using it.

Anyone know of a clean (or slightly dirty) way to just grab this stream?

Comment: Still consider using [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `HttpClient` - there is not much to write for either case, so maybe "re-write" is not a big problem...

Comment: Do the overloads which take a `HttpCompletionOption` not work for this usage?

Comment: You absolutely need ResponseHeadersRead as the HttpCompletionOption, but the problem I am facing is getting access to the stream.

Comment: I assumed that if you use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` then the `Stream` returned by `HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` would be zero-copy (unbuffered) and pull directly off the wire. Is this not the case? Very surprised if so.

Comment: ReadAsStreamAsync creates a new FixedMemoryStream (int.MaxValue) and copies into that. Not what I am looking for...